# How can I extract big image using Selenium & Java correctly?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm using the following code and struggling with snippet, provided below:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        // List of all articles included in the collection
        List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Setup ChromeDriver using WebDriverManager
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        // Set Chrome options and capabilities
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        // Additional configurations
        /*chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");*/

        // Connecting to ChromeDriver
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get("https://gearbest.net");

        // Collecting all products
        List<WebElement> newArrivals = driver.findElements(By.
                className("like_products_item"));

        // class of the whole element
        newArrivals.forEach(arrivalObj -> {

            // Find the anchor (a) element within the found element
            WebElement anchorElement = arrivalObj.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
            // Get the value of the "href" attribute (URL) from the anchor element
            String url = anchorElement.getAttribute("href");
            // WebElement arrival = arrivalObj.findElement(By.className("themes_prod"));
            String title = anchorElement.getAttribute("title"); // title of element
            // Find the element with class "price_data" within the found element
            WebElement priceElement = arrivalObj.findElement(By.className("price_data"));
            // Get the text content of the price element
            String price = priceElement.getText();
            // Redirect to the img link
            driver.navigate().to(url);
            // Get the current URL after navigation
            String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            // Get the value of the "data-src" attribute (photo URL) from the image element
            WebElement firstImgElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".lazyload[src*='" + currentUrl + "']"));
            // Get the value of the data-src attribute
            String img = firstImgElement.getAttribute("data-src");

            articleList.add(new Article(img, url, title, price));

            // Close the browser
            driver.quit();
        });

        articleList.forEach(System.out::println);
        articleList.forEach(article -> feedAdd(article.getImg(), article.getTitle(), article.getUrl(), article.getPrice()));
    }
```

To [extract image](https://gearbest.net/products/ai-box-android-11wireless-carplay-wireless-android-auto-for-volkswagen-mercedes-audi-skoda-kia-car-multimedia-player-car-ai-box-simblife?VariantsId=23325) using existing logic. The problem is it doesn't work and debug is freezing, for some reason.

I have already also tried to adapt snippets, as for instance:

1. ```
        // Find the image element using CSS Selector
        WebElement imgElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.transition4.lazyloaded"));

        // Get the value of the "data-src" attribute
        String dataSrcValue = imgElement.getAttribute("data-src");
   ```

   and accordingly:
2. ```
        // Find the image element using XPath
        WebElement imgElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='transition4 lazyloaded']"));

        // Get the value of the "data-src" attribute
        String dataSrcValue = imgElement.getAttribute("data-src");
   ```

and still it doesn't work.

Can someone recommend me, please, the use case how to write it correctly? I would really appreciate it, because the website is using JS while loading the image and it's hard to find the way how to extract based on the class extracting or similar.

*UPD #1*:

This [version of the code](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/46eac7b5ce6f31d2fa572e5a9b61d686#file-code-3-java-L46) returns me 8 elements, as I need per requirements in the `List<WebElement> productElements`, but in the console [all elements](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/b3dd4f8662efec38cd650578ea9861a4#file-console-output-L3) return me:

```
Product Image URL: null
```

for some reason.

*UPD #2*:

This version of code is [working finally good](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/b8ba76d7c3e4914f003a9c87f6f69bb4), but returns me [duplicated elements](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/da858848efde4868ba75cef64c6774de), I have already tried to use [Set](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/ee512c627f15092ed9be8337c036ac0a), but I don't have any outputs in the console:

[image]

*Article* class is as provided below:

```
public class Article {
    private String img;
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String price;

    public Article(String img, String url, String title, String price) {
        this.img = img;
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Article{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", img='" + img + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact error are you getting? I suspect you are having problems with this redirect to the image URL, but if you have an URL already, you can simply download the URL, without using Selenium, using any HTTP client. I can write a full answer with this idea.

Comment: @JoãoFarias, thank you for not ignoring my question. I'm expecting problem with getting the big image on the provided page with attached DOM. Could you show me, please,  how to do it with HTTP client?

Comment: I need to extract from the [provided page](https://gearbest.net/products/ai-box-android-11wireless-carplay-wireless-android-auto-for-volkswagen-mercedes-audi-skoda-kia-car-multimedia-player-car-ai-box-simblife?VariantsId=23325) or from the [main page](https://gearbest.net) the same good.

Comment: If someone provides any examples how to prevent the usage of JS via Selenium, I would really appreciate, as well, because it should work, with no doubt, or should I handle the usage of JS via Selenium to receive photos based on goods.